# Convert __declspec to _export C++

Tags: c++

I am converting the following function. But the new converted function is not executed. Any ideas?

Old Function
extern "C"
DWORD __declspec(dllexport) FAR MyFunc (char *value1, int *value2)

New Function
extern "C"
DWORD _export FAR MyFunc (char *value1, int *value2)

Comment: any errors? have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: What's wrong with the `__declspec(dllexport)`? What's the `_export` definition? Check if you're using the correct DLL, and if the symbol was exported.

Comment: The problem is fixed. The program was written in Delphi C++ builder. When i compiled the program, the compiler povides specific index for that function. But I was calling that function by using fixed index. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

_export is obsolete in the newer versions of Visual C++, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/107501/EN-US/).

Let me cite [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B123870&x=5&y=14): **It is not possible to maintain a single source for 16-bit and 32-bit code by simply replacing __export with _declspec() because _declspec() is a storage class modifier and __export is a type modifier.** The article states, that _export only works for 16-bit programs. So you should actually produce a 16-bit program and DLL.

Comment: All links here are now non-existent.